# Why can't I assign location.hash to a variable?

Tags: javascript

Why is it that I can get the value of `location.hash` when I call it like so:

```
> location.hash
"#my-hash-value"
```

But when I call it like so, it's undefined:

```
> var foo = location.hash
undefined
```

I'm missing something obvious. This is in Firefox.

Comment: Try displaying `foo`, not the return value of the statement `var foo = ...`

Comment: Ah ha. JavaScript gets me every time.

Comment: `var foo = location.hash` is not an expression but a statement and doesn’t return anything. But `foo` should hold the value as expected.

Comment: @mlissner It's not like JavaScript is the only language that works like this ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Statement doesn't return a value, but the variable is set. Try

```
console.log(a)
```